# Project not building properly in Android Studio using emulator

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I am going through the "Building Your First App" steps on the official Android site ([link](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html)). I have finished the first class, where you make a simple text field that can have text entered into it, and if you click a box beside the text field, the text entered will be sent to another screen.

However, when I run the app (using an emulator), the app is not building properly. I've changed some of the strings in strings.xml and they won't update, I'm only seeing what they were originally for some reason, and clicking the send button still does nothing. However, the preview I see when I view the XML files shows them displaying the correct Strings, so I don't understand why the app doesn't update on the emulator. [Here's a screenshot of what I mean.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4ca8.png)

This is my first time using Android Studio and my first time playing around with Android, but I don't get why it won't update.

I have uploaded the following on pastebin:

- [MyActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/fb2LTV4d)
- [DisplayMessageActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/DqWTEMNP)
- [activity_my.xml](http://pastebin.com/Q6YdLUw0)
- [activity_display_message.xml](http://pastebin.com/k2sh2cax)
- [strings.xml](http://pastebin.com/9Pg1GuLa)

If someone has a tip to help me through this, that would be appreciated.

Comment: I've seen your app and it runs normally. What do you want to see?

Comment: When I run the emulator, the textfield should say "Richard's Message" and I should be able to type something in the textfield, press the "Send" button, and see the text in another window, but instead the emualtor displays "Enter a message" and pressing the "Send" button does nothing. It's like the latest version of the app is not being compiled on the emulator. [See this screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/JoPsvFL.png), where the XML "preview" is correct (on the left), whereas what the emulator displays is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delete the app from the emulator. It could be that the app wont be new compiled because no sourcecode has changed, but "only" resource files. So instead of launching a new version of the app, the old, already installed version is brought to the front (started)

And to the button not responding: You dont set a `OnClickListener` onto your button.

In `onCreate` of MyActivity you should add the following:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        sendMessage(v);
    }
}
```

And in your `activity_my.xml` add the following attribute to your `<Button>`

```
android:id="@+id/button"
```

Comment: Yes I figured this out a few minutes ago, I just wiped the emulator and when I ran the app again I see the correct version now and it performs correctly. Thanks for answering.